# M2E PRO - Blank Website after installing

Tags: php, magento, http-status-code-404

I have tried to install M2E Pro to my magento website and it makes the full website blank and until I uninstall it.

I contacted M2E Pro and they said they tried to login and said they could not login to my Magento Connect - they got a 404 error.

What would cause this and how can i fix it?

Comment: If you're getting a blank screen in PHP, it means there's been a fatal error — configure and check your server logs to report PHP errors, and then post the error here.

Comment: Did you got any error in error log?